# Formatting a Two Dimensional Expanding Dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

How to write a two dimensional recursive function in python where my input looks something like this:

```
{   'Tj634f': {   'child': ['Tj256f', 'Tj996f'],
                      'title': 'FSIT'},
    'Tj227f': {'child': None, 'title': 'MEGP'},
    'Tj727f': {'child': None, 'title': 'MSIG/OF'},
    'Tj738f': {'child': None, 'title': 'EDVAN'},
    'Tj279f': {'child': None, 'title': 'L-L3dary'},
    'Tj230f': {'child': None, 'title': 'Mgea-Prog'},
    'Tj256f': {   'child': [   'Tj227f',
                               'Tj727f',
                               'Tj738f',
                               'Tj279f',
                               'Tj230f'],
                  'title': 'man'},
    'Tj996f': {   'child': [   'Tj997f',
                               'Tj998f',
                               'Tj999f',
                               'Tj800f'],
                  'title': 'Aut'},
    'Tj997f': {'child': None, 'title': 'DCGP'},
    'Tj998f': {'child': None, 'title': 'DBGP/PF'},
    'Tj999f': {'child': None, 'title': 'E-xAN'},
    'Tj800f': {'child': None, 'title': 'L-L3dary'},
    'root': 'Tj634f'}
```

and my output should look like this:

```
{    ('FSIT', 'Tj634f'): {  ('Aut', 'Tj996f') : [ ('DCGP','Tj997f'),
                                                  ('DBGP/PF','Tj998f'),
                                                  ('E-xAN','Tj999f'),
                                                  ('L-L3dary','Tj800f')],
                            ('man', 'Tj256f')": [ ('MEGP', 'Tj227f'),
                                                  ('MSIG/OF', 'Tj727f'),
                                                  ('EDVAN', 'Tj738f'),
                                                  ('L-L3dary', 'Tj279f'),
                                                  ('Mgea-Prog','Tj230f')]
                          }
}
```

However the levels in the dictionary are

```
FSIT 
   - man
      -- MEGP
      -- MSIG/OF
   - aut
      -- DCGP
      -- DBGP/PF
```

is variable in two dimensions one axis in depth `FSIT --> man --> MEGP --> ...` and also in breadth

```
FSIT
  -man
  -aut
  -rlt
    .
    .
    .
```

help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {
    'Tj634f': {'child': ['Tj256f', 'Tj996f'], 'title': 'FSIT'},
    'Tj227f': {'child': None, 'title': 'MEGP'},
    'Tj727f': {'child': None, 'title': 'MSIG/OF'},
    'Tj738f': {'child': None, 'title': 'EDVAN'},
    'Tj279f': {'child': None, 'title': 'L-L3dary'},
    'Tj230f': {'child': None, 'title': 'Mgea-Prog'},
    'Tj256f': {'child': ['Tj227f', 'Tj727f', 'Tj738f', 'Tj279f', 'Tj230f'], 'title': 'man'},
    'Tj996f': {'child': ['Tj997f', 'Tj998f', 'Tj999f', 'Tj800f'], 'title': 'Aut'},
    'Tj997f': {'child': None, 'title': 'DCGP'},
    'Tj998f': {'child': None, 'title': 'DBGP/PF'},
    'Tj999f': {'child': None, 'title': 'E-xAN'},
    'Tj800f': {'child': None, 'title': 'L-L3dary'},
    'root': 'Tj634f'
}

def reformat(dictionary, roots):
    value = None

    for root in roots:
        sub_dictionary = dictionary[root]

        if sub_dictionary['child']:
            if value is None:
                value = {}
            value[(sub_dictionary['title'], root)] = reformat(dictionary, sub_dictionary['child'])
        else:
            if value is None:
                value = []
            value.append((sub_dictionary['title'], root))

    return value


print(reformat(dictionary, [dictionary['root']]))
```

Somewhat fragile in that it assumes all elements at the same level all have children or all don't have children.

**OUTPUT (reformatted for readability)**

```
{
('FSIT', 'Tj634f'):
    {
    ('man', 'Tj256f'):
        [
        ('MEGP', 'Tj227f'),
        ('MSIG/OF', 'Tj727f'),
        ('EDVAN', 'Tj738f'),
        ('L-L3dary', 'Tj279f'),
        ('Mgea-Prog', 'Tj230f')
        ],
    ('Aut', 'Tj996f'):
        [
        ('DCGP', 'Tj997f'),
        ('DBGP/PF', 'Tj998f'),
        ('E-xAN', 'Tj999f'),
        ('L-L3dary', 'Tj800f')
        ]
    }
}
```